# Pandas Dataframe plot method not interpreting color parameter properly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following colors variable that contains the RGBA values of the colours I would like my bar graphs to be.

```
colors = [(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
  (0.9625172106584595, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
  (0.8426095407791366, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
  (0.7803353041224589, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
  (0.7778812667044626, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
  (0.7527658540536163, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
  (0.7322264517696606, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
  (0.6348343727221187, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
  (0.5364622985340568, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
  (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)]
```

However, it seems like all of the bar graphs are only taking the colour of the first value

```
reg_graph = reg_df.plot(kind="barh",figsize=(10,6),color=colors)
reg_graph.set_title("Number of records by region",fontsize=15)
```

[image]

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

-------- EDIT ---------

I have included more code from my jupyter notebook

```
reg_df = pd.DataFrame({"Records per region":df["Region"].value_counts()})
reg_df["Region Name"] = reg_df.index.to_series().map(codes_to_names_map["Region"])
#reg_df = reg_df.set_index("Region Name")
reg_df = reg_df.sort_values("Records per region")
reg_df
```

[image]

```
#Applying a colour gradient for better data visualization
max_value = reg_df["Records per region"].max()
min_value = reg_df["Records per region"].min()

def calculate_color(value):
    MAX_COLOR = (0.5,0,0)
    MIN_COLOR = (1,0,0)
    diff_in_color = tuple(map(lambda i, j: i - j, MAX_COLOR, MIN_COLOR))
    calculate_diff = tuple((value-min_value)/(max_value-min_value) * i for i in diff_in_color)
    return tuple(map(lambda i, j: i + j, calculate_diff, MIN_COLOR))
    
colors = [i for i in reg_df["Records per region"].apply(calculate_color)]
colors
```

[image]

```
# Plotting the bar graph
reg_graph = reg_df.plot(kind="barh",figsize=(10,6),color=colors)
reg_graph.set_title("Number of records by region",fontsize=15)
```

This final bit of code produces the graph in red despite the colors array being different RGB values.

Comment: `color` argument works fine with me. Could you provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Also try to make sure you're using the latest matplotlib and pandas versions.

Comment: I am using the latest matplotlib and pandas version